# ORACLE - Llenar Combobox desde base datos

Tags: netbeans, oracle-sqldeveloper

Tengo un JCombobox en Java, el cual quiero llenar con informacion de la base de datos. Pero obtengo un error de conexion. Dejaré el codigo que llevo.

**Clase Usuarios - Metodo Consultar Usuarios**

```
public void Consultar_Usuarios(JComboBox cbox_usuarios){
    
    conexion cn = new conexion();
    
    PreparedStatement pst = null;
    ResultSet result = null;

    //Creamos la Consulta SQL
    String SSQL = "SELECT nombre, apellido_paterno FROM usuarios ORDER BY nombre ASC";

    //Establecemos bloque try-catch-finally
    try {
   
        //Establecemos conexión con la BD 
        cn.conectar();

        //Preparamos la consulta SQL
        pst = cn.getCon().prepareStatement(SSQL);
    
        //Ejecutamos la consulta
        result = pst.executeQuery();

        //LLenamos nuestro ComboBox   
        while(result.next()){

            cbox_usuarios.addItem(result.getString(SSQL));
        }
        }catch(SQLException e) {

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }finally{
    
            try {
    
                cn.getCon().close();
                result.close();
                result=null;
            }catch(SQLException ex) {
        
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex);
            }
        }
}
```

**CLASE CONEXION**

```
package conexion;

import java.sql.*;

public class conexion {

    private Connection con;

    public boolean conectar() {
        try {
            String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe";
            String usuario= "PROG";
            String pass = "prg1231";
        
            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            this.con = DriverManager.getConnection(url,usuario,pass);
            return true;
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("Error de conexion " + ex);
            return false;
        }
    }
    public Connection getCon() {
        return con;
    }

    public void desconectar() {
        try {
            this.con.close();
        }catch(Exception ex) {      
        }
    }
}
```

**FORMULARIO** Donde tengo el Jcombobox. Omiti mucho codigo, porque no era necesario, deje lo principal para este caso.

```
import Datos.Usuarios;
public class MenuConyuge extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public MenuConyuge() {
        initComponents();
    
        Usuarios usr = new Usuarios();
        usr.Consultar_Usuarios(JCombo_Nombre_Usuario1);
    }
    
    private javax.swing.JComboBox<String> JCombo_Nombre_Usuario1;
}
```

Y finalmente dejo una captura de mi error, sucede cuando abro la ventana del Registro del Conyugue del usuario. El cual no sé porque sucede ese error. Me pregunto que hice mal.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola amigo tu problema puede ser que no has agregado la libreria a tu proyecto. Si ya tienes descargada la libreria  debes seguir los siguientes pasos en Netbeans:

Click sobre la pestana proyectos ubicada en la parte izquierda de la pantalla 
Abre al arbol de directorios y ubicate en Libraries
Click derecho en ADD JAR/Folder
En el explorador de archivos busca tu libreria.jar
Cuando la tengas seleccionada presiona sobre el botón Abrir
Con esto tu libreria se agregará a tu proyecto.
Ejecuta nuevamente tu aplicación y me cuentas.

Comment: @Cheox Publique una respuesta, la cual soluciona el problema. Pero ahora para agregar 2 campos al combobox. Ojo aqui: **2 campos** NO ** 2 items** para el checkbox. Me explico. Que me muestre nombre y apellido junto y no por separado. Pense en lo siguiente: un select nombre, apellido primero para la consulta y luego en el while que publique en la respuesta: 
Poner lo siguiente: `cbox_usuarios.addItem(result.getString("NOMBRE"+"APELLIDO"));` Pero eso no funciona, nuevamente arroja el error de columna invalida.

Comment: Ya publiqué la respuesta para que otras personas que tengan el mismo problema la pueden utilizar, al final incluí  unas soluciones para tu problema de concatenación en el jcombobox. No olvides si ni respuesta te ha servido para resolver tu problema puedes marcarla como usada seleccionando el check ( ✓ ) situado a su izquierda de la pantalla. Saludos

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tu problema puede ser que no has agregado la libreria a tu proyecto. Si ya tienes descargada la libreria debes seguir los siguientes pasos en Netbeans:

1. Click sobre la pestana proyectos ubicada en la parte izquierda de la pantalla
2. Selecciona tu proyecto
3. Abre al arbol de directorios y ubicate en Libraries
4. Click derecho en ADD JAR/Folder
5. En el explorador de archivos busca tu libreria.jar
6. Cuando la tengas seleccionada da clisk en el botón abrir
7. Ejecuta nuevamente tu aplicación y funcionará.

Respecto a tu segundo problema  para unir el nombre y apellido_paterno puedes usar la funcion  CONCAT(). A continuación te dejo un ejemplo de consulta en mysql
(ya que Oracle no manejo) para que la uses como ejemplo en tu tabla usuarios.

```
  select CONCAT(nombre, ' ', apellido_paterno ) as nombre from usuarios ORDER BY nombre ASC
```

Si no prefieres modificar tu consulta sql lo puedes hacer en el código java se la siguiente manera:

```
while(result.next()){

            cbox_usuarios.addItem( result.getString("nombre") +" "+ result.getString("apellido_paterno") );
        }
```

Espero haberte ayudado

Comment: Si justamente eso era, y sobre la consulta no se me habia ocurrido, tampoco pense en que la concatenacion en java podia ser asi, gracias!!

Comment: De nada amigo, fué un gusto ayudarte.

Comment: Revisando, la consulta con CONCAT() me traia los resultados pero todo junto, y para separar el nombre con el apellido por un espacio, lo hice asi: `SELECT CONCAT(nombre, (' '||apellido_paterno)) AS "NOMBRE" FROM USUARIOS;`. Gracias